# Messages Delivered Through IIS No Longer Appearing in Incoming Queue

Tags: iis, msmq

I am attempting to send MSMQ messages to a remote private queue. I have the MSMQ server configured to receive incoming messages through IIS.

This configuration was working fine, however messages are no longer being placed in the incoming message queue.  The IIS logs are showing a response of 200 indicating success, and the sent messages are appearing in the outbound queue and indicate they were delivered.

The queues are write-permissioned to everyone.

The queue connection looks like such

DIRECT=https://somedomain.com/msmq/private$/queueName

Thanks!

Edit: I was finally able to work around this issue by using a non-transactional queue. One thing that really helped was [enabling dead letter queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789035.aspx).  This allowed us to see that we were actually getting a 400 error from the destination server.  After that, we implemented [http msmq message redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731558%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)  this was necesary since the msmq server specified from the source to destination wasn't what the destination server expected.  This still resulted in 400 errors so finally we made the queue non-transactional and everything was working as expected.

Comment: Is your queue transactional?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and then mark it as such. This is clearer and will help others if they have the same problem. Thanks